OKTA Redirect URI error: The 'redirect_uri' does not match the redirection URI
I am building an Web app where i have okta to login using redirect model + OIDC. I am able to successfully login and perform 2fa and create an access and ID token.


var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var qs = require('querystring');
var { Strategy } = require('passport-openidconnect');
const axios = require('axios');

// source and import environment variables
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.okta.env' })
//require('dotenv').config({ path: '.entra.env' })
const { ORG_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const { profile } = require('console');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'CanYouLookTheOtherWay',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfigurationRequest
let logout_url, id_token;
let _base = ORG_URL.slice(-1) == '/' ? ORG_URL.slice(0, -1) : ORG_URL;
console.log ('Base URL - ' + _base);
axios
  .get(`${_base}/.well-known/openid-configuration`)
  .then(res => {
    if (res.status == 200) {
      let { issuer, authorization_endpoint, token_endpoint, userinfo_endpoint, end_session_endpoint } = res.data;
      logout_url = end_session_endpoint;

      console.log ('Authorization Endpoint - ' +authorization_endpoint);

      // Set up passport
      passport.use('oidc', new Strategy({
        issuer,
        authorizationURL: authorization_endpoint,
        tokenURL: token_endpoint,
        userInfoURL: userinfo_endpoint,
        clientID: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/authorization-code/callback',
        scope: 'profile offline_access',
        maxAge: 0
      }, (issuer, profile, context, idToken, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {
        console.log(`OIDC response: ${JSON.stringify({
          issuer, profile, context, idToken,
          accessToken, refreshToken, params
        }, null, 2)}\n*****`);
        id_token = idToken;
        return done(null, profile);
      }));
    }
    else {
      console.log(`Unable to reach the well-known endpoint. Are you sure that the ORG_URL you provided (${ORG_URL}) is correct?`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

passport.serializeUser((user, next) => {
  next(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, next) => {
  next(null, obj);
});

function ensureLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }

  res.redirect('/login')
}

app.use('/', indexRouter);

app.use('/login', passport.authenticate('oidc'));

app.use('/authorization-code/callback',
  // https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/458
  passport.authenticate('oidc', { failureMessage: true, failWithError: true }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  }
);

app.use('/profile', ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render('profile', { authenticated: req.isAuthenticated(), user: req.user, title: 'Profile' });
});

app.use('/auth/2fa', ensureLoggedIn, (req,res) =>{
    console.log ("******In MFA Page******");
    passport.authenticate('oidc', {
      scope: ['openid', 'profile'],
      prompt: 'login',
      callbackURL: '/authorization-code/callback/2fa'
    })(req,res);
});



app.use('/authorization-code/callback/2fa',
  // https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/458
  passport.authenticate('oidc'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("In req");
    console.log(req);
    res.redirect('/secure_page')
  }
);


app.get('/secure_page', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  res.send('<h1>2FA Success! You are on a secure page.</h1>');
});


app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message + (err.code && ' (' + err.code + ')' || '') +
    (req.session.messages && ": " + req.session.messages.join("\n. ") || '');
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;



Now customer is in Profile Page with a valid session which has a button to invoke 2FA. When user clicks on button it invokes the below code:


app.use('/auth/2fa', ensureLoggedIn, (req,res) =>{
    console.log ("******In MFA Page******");
    passport.authenticate('oidc', {
      scope: ['openid', 'profile'],
      prompt: 'login',
      callbackURL: '/authorization-code/callback/2fa'
    })(req,res);
});



It successfully runs the above code and displays the login screen first and then the 2FA using SMS. Once i have successfully entered the credentials it throws an error as below:

The 'redirect_uri' does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request. (invalid_grant)

It never calls the below method:


app.use('/authorization-code/callback/2fa',
  // https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/458
  passport.authenticate('oidc'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("In req");
   console.log(req);
  }
);



I have both the URLs slated below specified in OKTA under the app.

http://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback
http://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback/2fa

Ideally i want the app to redirect to

http://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback/2fa and execute the below code.



app.use('/authorization-code/callback/2fa',
  // https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/458
  passport.authenticate('oidc'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("In req");
    console.log(req);
    res.redirect('/secure_page')
  }
);


app.get('/secure_page', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  res.send('<h1>2FA Success! You are on a secure page.</h1>');
});



I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"I have both the URLs slated below specified in OKTA under the app." - but that doesn't mean, you can switch between them at will. You need to finish the auth process by passing the same redirect URI, as you used when you started it. And apparently, that is not the case here
